# Visual Basic Key down and Keyup

Tags: vb.net

OK so I'm writing a program that has a timer set to 10 ms that keeps checking the state of a button. When the button is down, i want it to do a key down of the keyboard key i set, and the button is released, i want the set key to be up.

Iv tried `Sendkeys.send` but as the program is on a timer, its just going to keep spamming that key. Iv also been trying to use `keybd_event(87, 0, 2, 0)`. With this one, it presses the W key, as it should, but only once, then comes up with this error...

`PInvokeStackImbalance` was detected

A call to `PInvoke` function `'Mercury!Mercury.Player1::keybd_event'` has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed `PInvoke` signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the `PInvoke` signature match the target unmanaged signature.

I have no idea what this means but if its useful to know, could someone please explain it? Thanks
So yea is it possible to hold a key down within a timer?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Are you trying to remap keys? If so, why not just handle the KeyDown event of the form and have it remap the keys there?

Comment: No, im trying to simulate a keypress when I click a button on the form

Comment: And where exactly where will the keypresses be focused?

Comment: What key it will simulate pressing? Could you explain what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to send the keypresses to? A textbox, different form, different application, etc?

Comment: Oh right. Sorry, i didn't understand. I'm trying to make act as if the user is pressing that key on their keyboard. For example, if i had the button set to the start key on my keyboard, when i click the button, it would act as if the user has pressed the start key and open the start menu thing. If that makes sense.
Thanks for this by the way

Comment: PInvokeStackImbalance usually occurs when you have the wrong **data type** in your API declaration.  Most likely you picked up an API that was meant for VB6 and didn't realize it.  In general you need to change Long to Integer.  Show us your API declaration and we can help correct it.

Comment: Also, when you click the Button **YOUR** button will have focus, so the keystrokes will go to your button.  Are you trying to target your own app?...or external applications?

Comment: OK thanks for that, Idle. Here's what I'm using currently:
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Comment: OMG thank you Idle!! Changing Long to Integer did exactly what i wanted. you have no idea how long iv been looking for this answer haha. Thank you!

Comment: How do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Answering your last question; No, im using XNA frameworks to take input from my Xbox 360 controller and the timer keeps checking for button presses and stuff. Theres probably a much simpler way to code it all but im a bit of a noob lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment as answer based on response:

> OMG thank you Idle!! Changing Long to Integer did exactly what i
>   wanted. you have no idea how long iv been looking for this answer
>   haha. Thank you!

PInvokeStackImbalance usually occurs when you have the wrong data type in your API declaration. Most likely you picked up an API that was meant for VB6 and didn't realize it. In general you need to change Long to Integer. Show us your API declaration and we can help correct it.